# Server Error ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Al hacer render a la aplicacion obtengo este error  me señala la linea 17... no entiendo porque

```
 15 |     <App />
  16 |   </React.StrictMode>,
> 17 |   document.getElementById('root')
     |  ^
  18 | );
  19 | 
  20 | const Home: NextPage = () => {
```

Comment: Falta información para saber qué pasa realmente. Publica todo el archivo `Home` y un screenshot del error en la consola.

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs renderiza desde el servidor y no tiene acceso al `window.document` (lado del cliente). Hay trucos para poder acceder como usar un useEffect

```
    useEffect(() => {
        document.getElementById('root')
    },[])
```